# Spark number of cores used by driver

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I can set number of cores using spark.driver.cores for driver in case of cluster mode. But how many cores are used in case of client and local mode for driver

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your application locally with master local[*], Here * mention they will use all free cores in your local system and if you are using the local[n], Here n is number of cores you want to use in your application. Its a core which is used by your application in local mode because when you run your application in local driver and executers are started in single JVM.

Comment: Can you as well specify number of cores in case of client mode

Comment: yes you can when you start your application with master local[n], Here you can specify n value as number of threads for local mode